# convert time using select option . Using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> I saw this code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/174/. I decided to modify the code for my
>   project because it's kinda similar.
>    I added another drop down as origin (left) convert to (right)

Can you guys please help how to convert the time and place it in the input textfield 
this is the code that I added/edit 
p.s. i didn't change the javascript code.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.location').each(function() {
        var timeZone = $(this).data('tz');
        
        var now = moment().tz(timeZone).format('HH:mm');
        $(this).append( now );
    });
});
```

```html
<select>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Africa/Tripoli">Tripoli: </span></span><br /><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Europe/London">London: </span><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Europe/London">London: </span><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Asia/Tokyo">Tokyo </span><option>
</select>
<p>CONVERT TO</p>
<select>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Africa/Tripoli">Tripoli: </span></span><br /><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Europe/London">London: </span><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Europe/London">London: </span><option>
<option><span class="location" data-tz="Asia/Tokyo">Tokyo </span><option>

</select>

<input type="text" id="gettime" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get Bombay time
alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));

// get Singapore time
alert(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));

// get London time
alert(calcTime('London', '+1'));
});


function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();
   
    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
   
    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
   
    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```